# Display sObject List in Visualforce page

Tags: list, sobject

I want to create an overview of a list which contains content from different objects. I will try to add in this list the files, tasks, events, emails and notes.
I would like to show this list on the account or contact record so that the sales representative can get a quick overview of the correspondence. I know how can I store all information of different objects in one list, but how can I display this list in a visualforce page?

```
sObject[] results = new sObject[0];
results.addAll([SELECT Title FROM ContentDocument]);
results.addAll([SELECT Subject FROM Task]);
results.addAll([SELECT Subject FROM Event]);
results.addAll([SELECT Subject From EmailMessage]);
results.addAll([SELECT Title FROM Note]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to create a custom list controller. Plenty of documentation on this:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_standard_list_controllers
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm